# I am having trouble with SQL Server Express's identity feature

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, identity-column

I'm working with SQL Server Express, I created this table

```
CREATE TABLE inventory
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    description nvarchar(50),
    quantity int,
    price money
)
```

when I insert this statement:

```
INSERT INTO inventory VALUES('water', 20, 1.50)
```

I get this error:

> The number of columns in the query and the table must match. [ Number
>   of columns in query = 3, Number of columns in table = 4 ]

and when I put this statement:

```
INSERT INTO inventory VALUES(1, 'water', 20, 1.50)
```

I get this error:

> The column cannot be modified. [ Column name = id ]

I thought identity would auto increment the value, so can't I do either, and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

You must explicitly specify columns in your insert

```
insert Inventory(Description, Quantity, Price) values ( ...)
```

Comment: but I haven't done so in regular sql server, why is this specific to this db? Thanks though I can finally start the coding.

Comment: @user1393108: that's a **basic** SQL technique - you should always define the list of columns you're inserting into. With `IDENTITY`, since SQL Server (**all** editions - this is **NOT** specific to the Express edition) will determine the value itself, you are not allowed to insert any values into it - and so you need to omit it from the list of columns you're inserting into.

Comment: You can use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON` if you want to set identity manually though